# Is there a way to edit/manage/save Picasa web album photos directly from Lightroom?

Tags: lightroom, picasa, plugin

I am trying to edit my photos directly from Picasa Library on lightroom and replace them with the new photos, but I can't find a good plugin. I found "[Jeffrey’s “Export to PicasaWeb” Lightroom Plugin](http://regex.info/blog/lightroom-goodies/picasaweb)" but it only uploads to Picasa.

**So here is what I want to do:**

- Open the Lightroom application
- Be able to see all my Picasa web albums
- Edit the photo
- Save it (overwrite the current photo in the Picasa web albums)
- Not lose any comments on the photo

Because I have comments on each photo and I don't want to lose those comments when editing the photo, it is very crucial to only replace the photo.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion would be to learn how to use Lightroom in it full capabilities as Lightroom manages a catalog database for images and another database for edits where as Picasa uses another method of tracking images and saves edits directly to the same file or another file if you are dealing with raw images.  Lightroom does allow for a way to leave tags and other forms of commenting photos that can be removed on an image export.

Comment: I am not using Picasa at all. I am using [Picasa Web Albums](https://picasaweb.google.com)

Comment: My miss understanding, I havent used Picasa Web Albums but I suspect that it has even less features then Picasa.

Answer (score 1):

Lr and the Friedl Picasa plugin can do all that, sort of.

Lr and the plugin do not, of course, know about the photos you have already uploaded to Picasa by other means. How could they? But going forward you import into Lr. Edit. Put into a new album created in the Picasa publish service. Publish. Later, if you change certain parameters (and there is a list of triggering events you can modify in the publish service), the photo will be marked for re-publishing, and if you do so the changes get set to Picasa. And the plugin has some features for importing comments as well.

Perhaps you are misunderstanding how Lr and publish services work? IOW, the Picasa plugin is a PUBLISH SERVICE. That's all it does; Lr itself is what you use to edit the photo.